# How to debug a segmentation fault 11 on TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I installed cuda 8 and the new tensorflow 1.0. 
When I run "import tensorflow as tf" I get the following:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.8.0.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.5.dylib locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.8.0.dylib locally
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Knowing that nvcc -V gives the following:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Oct_30_22:18:43_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.54
```

Any idea how to fix this segmentation fault?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing a library in your local cuda installation. E.g., `/usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib` was missing for me after trying to install `CUDA Toolkit 8.0` locally (possibly because I installed the drivers first before the toolkit, as this ancient thread suggests: https://render.otoy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1859). Re-running the installer for just the driver installed it properly, and also symlinked it to another name (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3263#issuecomment-232184358).

Lastly, double check your environment variable paths, see if `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` looks right.

As an aside, I still saw some warnings when testing the install, e.g. `The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.`. These just are suggesting to build from source (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8037), rather than using `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu`.